# JS function not working on added rows

Tags: javascript, jquery

the third JS function changes comma to dot on the existing rows, but when I add new row with the first function it doesn't work on the new rows. How can I correct this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#addPurchase").click(function()
    {
        $("#tablePurchases tr:last").after('<tr>'+
        '<td><input type="text" name="comment[]" style="width:250px;" maxlength="255" value="Hi!" /></td>'+
        '<td><input type="text" name="do[]" style="width:70px; text-align:right;" value="0.00" /></td>'+
        '<td><input type="text" name="dds[]" style="width:50px; text-align:right;" value="0.00" /></td>'+
        '</tr>');
    });

    $("#removePurchase").click(function(){
        if($("#tablePurchases tr").length>2) { $("#tablePurchases tr:last").remove();total(); };
    });

    $("#tablePurchases td:nth-child(2)").on('keyup',function(){
        $(this).children().val($(this).children().val().replace(",", "."));
    });

});
</script>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="addPurchase">Add</a>/
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="removePurchase">Remove</a><br />
<table style="font-family:'Book antiqua';" id="tablePurchases"><tbody>
<tr align="center">
<th>Field1</th>
<th>Field2</th>
<th>Field3</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" name="comment[]" style="width:250px;" maxlength="255" value="Hi!" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="do[]" style="width:70px; text-align:right;" value="0.00" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="dds[]" style="width:50px; text-align:right;" value="0.00" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" name="comment[]" style="width:250px;" maxlength="255" value="Hi!" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="do[]" style="width:70px; text-align:right; " value="0.00"/></td>
<td><input type="text" name="dds[]" style="width:50px; text-align:right; " value="0.00"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

When binding events to dynamically created elements, you need to use .on()'s delegated syntax.

Change:

```
$("#tablePurchases td:nth-child(2)").on('keyup',function(){
    $(this).children().val($(this).children().val().replace(",", "."));
});
```

to:

```
$('table').on('keyup', '#tablePurchases td:nth-child(2)', function(){
    $(this).children().val($(this).children().val().replace(",", "."));
});
```

Comment: Don't flood the document with the events. Move it to the table element.  `$("#tablePurchases").on('keyup', 'td:nth-child(2)'`